# Reshape in R - Summarizing Two Variables in a Wide Format

Tags: r, count, aggregate, reshape2

I am looking to reshape my data and aggregate it to "counts" similar to how a pivot table would work.

I have two columns: one with list of events and the second with attendees to an event (e.g.

```
 event | attendee
 birthday | Joe
 birthday | Jane
 birthday | Alex
 wedding  | Jane
 wedding  | Brad
```

etc.) I want to summarize it into one that counts up everything in column `"attendee"` so that I can see

```
event | n_attendees
birthday | 3
wedding  | 2
```

but for a larger set of data. How would you be able to condense it from the long format to a wide format in as few steps as possible while counting the second column? I can imagine how to do it on a pivot table in Excel, but I am having trouble reshaping it without having to list every event and count every list of attendees per event. My dataset is too large to do it like this.

Comment: `tapply(!is.na(df$attendee), df$event, FUN=sum)`

Comment: Using `aggregate` function

`aggregate(df$event,by = list(df$event),length)`